# Javascript date time formatting

Tags: javascript

I have a date value I'm getting current date time with it:

```
let date = new Date();
```

it gives me the current date and time.

But how can I get the current date but change hour to : 00:00 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the date object and set the hours to be 00:00:00.

```
let date = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))
```

It will get the current date but set the hours.

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet

```
let date = new Date()
console.log(date)
date.setHours(0)
date.setMinutes(0)
date.setSeconds(0)
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(new Date((new Date()).setMinutes(0)).setSeconds(0))
```